# refresh the textScrollList in maya with Python

Tags: maya

I have an array with lights , everytime I create a light it stores is my array.
I have a textScrollList that displays all lights in my Array.

When I add lights , it doesn't refersh the textScrollList.

Can someone tell me how I can do this , so everytime I make a light it display it in the textScrollList. Or with a refresh button.

Thanks !

Code I have now :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
lights=[]

myWindow = cmds.window(title='My Lights', wh=(200,400),sizeable =False )
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.showWindow(myWindow)

 LightsButton = cmds.button(label='Make Lights', command = "makeLights()", width =200,height = 25,align='center')


def makeLights():
    lights.append(cmds.shadingNode('aiAreaLight', asLight=True))




LightSelector = cmds.textScrollList( numberOfRows=8, allowMultiSelection=True,append=(lights), showIndexedItem=4, selectCommand = 'selectInTextList()' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function that will refresh the list with the lights. This can be called after you create a new light so it adds to the list. You can also add a refresh button to call this same function in case you add/delete lights in the scene, and it will update properly.

You don't need to add the lights to a list and keep track of it. Instead you can use `cmds.ls()` to collect all the lights in the scene. Unless you really do need the list for some reason, it's easy to edit the example below to use it:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


# Clear the listview and display the current lights in the scene.
def refreshList():
    # Clear all items in list.
    cmds.textScrollList(lightSelector, e=True, removeAll=True)

    # Collect all lights in the scene.
    allLights = cmds.ls(type='aiAreaLight')

    # Add lights to the listview.
    for obj in allLights:
        cmds.textScrollList(lightSelector, e=True, append=obj)


# Create a new light and add it to the listview.
def makeLights():
    lights.append(cmds.shadingNode('aiAreaLight', asLight=True))

    refreshList()


def selectInTextList():
    # Collect a list of selected items.
    # 'or []' converts it to a list when nothing is selected to prevent errors.
    selectedItems = cmds.textScrollList(lightSelector, q=True, selectItem=True) or []

    # Use a list comprehension to remove all lights that no longer exist in the scene.
    newSelection = [obj for obj in selectedItems if cmds.objExists(obj)]

    cmds.select(newSelection)


# Create window.
myWindow = cmds.window(title='My Lights', wh=(200,400), sizeable=False)
cmds.columnLayout()
cmds.showWindow(myWindow)

# Create interface items.
addButton = cmds.button(label='Make Lights', command='makeLights()', width=200, height=25, align='center')
lightSelector = cmds.textScrollList(numberOfRows=8, allowMultiSelection=True, append=cmds.ls(type='aiAreaLight'), showIndexedItem=4, selectCommand='selectInTextList()')
refreshButton = cmds.button(label='Refresh list', command='refreshList()', width=200, height=25, align='center')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's what I was looking for  :D Thank you very much !